# When running ng serve -o I'm getting an error

Tags: angular-cli

When I run the ng serve -o command I get the following error, and I have tried everything...deleting the node_modules folder and uninstalling angular cli, however, nothing seems to be resolving it.

```
Error: ./src/styles.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at C:\Users\{name}\Downloads\MyApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at C:\Users\{name}\Downloads\MyApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\{name}\Downloads\MyApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\{name}\Downloads\MyApp\node_modules\loader- 
    runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\{name}\Downloads\MyApp\node_modules\postcss- 
    loader\dist\index.js:56:7)

Error: ./src/app/app.component.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

Angular CLI Version:

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.6
Node: 15.12.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1102.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.6 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          11.2.6 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1102.6 (cli-only)
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything, I was able to resolve this by removing the reference to the ./src/styles.css in my angular.json file.

"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/assets"
],
"styles": [],

Then I removed the reference to the app.component.css from the styleUrls[] property in the component decorator of the app.component.ts file.

Component({
selector: 'ro-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

Not sure why I was initially getting the error, because I created the project using the angular-cli, and both stylesheets were empty.